# Target in knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I wonder if it's possable to use knockout to change target in html (`<div data-bind="`Here i want to change target with JS`"></div>`)

I have all my other info in javascript so it's a big problem for me.
Here is my javascript:

```
var libraryViewModel = {
        boxes: [
            {
                title: "Google",
                src: false,
                url: 'https://google.se',
            },
            {
                title: "Yahoo",
                src: false,
                url: 'https://se.yahoo.com',
            },
        ]

    };
```

...and html:

```
<a class="box" data-bind="attr: { href: url,'style': 'background-image: url('+ src +');' }">
        <h2 data-bind="text: title">Unnamed</h2>
    </a>
```

Please help. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: As you used in anchor tag, you can use attr to appropriately add some bindings. A more detailed info on what you need would help us to guide you

Comment: Can you do this: `<div data-bind="attr: { target: target}</div>`?

Comment: And in JS:`... target: '_blank' ...`..?

Comment: @Elias yes you can do this. `<div data-bind="attr: { target: target}</div>`, `target: '_blank'`
You can do it for any attribute of an html element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out this jsFiddle which should hopefully implement what you need.

The first thing I did was to apply your view model using knockout:

```
function libraryViewModel() {
  this.boxes = [{
      title: "Google",
      src: false,
      url: 'https://google.se',
    },
    {
      title: "Yahoo",
      src: false,
      url: 'https://se.yahoo.com',
    },
  ];

};

ko.applyBindings(new libraryViewModel())
```

And in the HTML I iterarte over each of the boxes and apply the href attribute and the other ones:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: boxes">

  <a class="box" data-bind="attr: { href: url,'style': 'background-image: url('+ src +');' }">
    <h2 data-bind="text: title">Unnamed</h2>
  </a>
</div>
```

This is the link to the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/internetbird/jfehbv3u/5/

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Tank you Sahi, but i’ve already do that. My problem was if I can change target with knockout JS.

Comment: @Elias, Well. when you want to change the target? on any event?

Comment: @Elias , Please supply more details. What is the exact flow that you trying to achive? When do you want the target to change? The whole idea of knockout is that if you change the viewmodel it automatically changes the UI

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. You can dynamically update any attribute of any HTML element with the `attr` binding.

Example fiddle:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  this.boxes = [{
      title: "Blank Target",
      url: 'https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/html-iframes.php',
      target: 'iframe_b'
    },
    {
      title: "Self Target",
      url: 'https://www.yelp.com',
      target: 'iframe_a'
    },
  ];

};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: boxes">
  <a class="box" data-bind="attr: { href: url, target: target}">
    <h2 data-bind="text: title">Unnamed</h2>
  </a>
</div>

<iframe name="iframe_a"></iframe>
<iframe name="iframe_b"></iframe>
```